# Transpose only certain columns in data.frame

Tags: r, reshape, data-manipulation

Here is the **data I have**:

```
           am   group  v1  v2  v3    v4
1  2015-10-31       A 693 803 700   17%
2  2015-10-31       B 524 859 302   77%
3  2015-10-31       C 266 675 86    7%
4  2015-10-31       D 376 455 650   65%
5  2015-11-30       A 618 715 200   38%
6  2015-11-30       B 249 965 215   54%
7  2015-11-30       C 881 106 184   24%
8  2015-11-30       D 033 047 492   46%
9  2015-12-31       A 229 994 720   19%
10 2015-12-31       B 539 543 332   57%
11 2015-12-31       C 100 078 590   24%
12 2015-12-31       D 517 413 716   57%
```

**Question:**
How can I transpose the data such that

1. transpose `v1-v4` and
2. make values in `am` as column variables
3. `group` variable is replicated by the number of `v1-v4`

The result I'd like to produce:

```
group metric 2015-10-31 2015-11-30 2015-12-31
    A     v1        693        618        229
    A     v2        803        715        994 
    A     v3        700        200        720
    A     v4        17%        38%        19%
    B     v1        524        249        539
    B     v2        859        965        543 
    B     v3        302        215        332
    B     v4        77%        54%        57%
    ...
```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
name <- mydata$am
data <- as.data.frame(t(mydata[, -1]))
colnames(mydata) <- name
```

This doesn't handle `group` variable the way I want.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You really want to mix data types in your resulting dataset? Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: It's for a table output that I'm preparing for `htmlTable`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The basic idea would be to go to a "long" format first, and then go into a "wide" format.

Here are a few ways to do this....

***`melt`*** + ***`dcast`***

```
library(data.table) ## or library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(as.data.table(mydf), id.vars = c("am", "group")), 
      group + variable ~ am, value.var = "value")
```

***`recast`***

(This is basically the same as melt+cast, but in one step.)

```
library(reshape2)
recast(mydf, group + variable ~ am, id.var = c("am", "group"))
```

***`gather`*** + ***`spread`***

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  gather(key, value, v1:v4) %>%
  spread(am, value)
```

***`pivot_longer` + `pivot_wider`***

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd %>% 
  mutate(across(v1:v4, as.character)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "metric", cols=v1:v4) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(group, metric), values_from = value,  names_from=am)
```

***`reshape`***

```
reshape(cbind(mydf[c(1, 2)], stack(mydf[-c(1, 2)])), 
        direction = "wide", idvar = c("group", "ind"), timevar = "am")
```